# 32bit dll used by VB6 program doesn't work in 64bit Win 7

Tags: windows, dll, vb6

1) a 32bit dll is placed in C:\Windows\SysWOW64

2) Registered using regasm.exe

3) While compiling, i set the target cpu to x86

I can add reference in my vb6 program but when i try to call the method within the dll, it failed. Error message as follow :

```
 "Runtime Error '-2147467261' object instance not set to an instance of an object"
```

Codes here :

```
Set m_objCLogon = CreateObject("CommonLogon.Logon")
strResult = m_objCLogon.ValidateLogin(p_strUserID, p_strEncryptedPwd, p_strAppID)
```

The code is pretty simple, just passing in the credentials for validation.

Anyone knows which part has gone wrong?

Comment: Judging from the error message the problem is not in the VB6 application, but in the DLL itself. You should have a look at the source of `ValidateLogin` instead.

Comment: Is it a .NET DLL or a COM/ActiveX DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly there's nothing wrong with the registration, the error message is a .NET exception message.  Your code is bombing on a NullReferenceException.  That's a very common exception and it is (nearly) always caused by a bug in your code.

You'll need to debug your code.  Do so with Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Select "Start external program" and set it to your vb6 program or c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vb6\vb6.exe.  Then Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.  Press F5 to start.

Comment: +1 And when Hans says you need to debug your code, he means the **.Net code** not the VB6 code.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would copy the DLL to the System32 directory (since it IS a VB6 32bit DLL) and I would use regsvr32 c:\Windows\System32\MyDLL.DLL.  Just like using it on any other 32 bit machine.